# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module yet other files in directory do not have issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, testing, syntax-error

I am testing some React-Native components. For context, my components are stored in the following manner:

```
project
-components
--componentA
---ComponentA.js
---__test__
----ComponentA.test.js
--componentB
---ComponentB.js
---__test__
----ComponentB.test.js
--componentC
---ComponentC.js
---__test__
----ComponentC.test.js
```

The components have import statements, like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
```

Components A and Components B rendered successfully and passed their respective tests. Component C is unable to have its test suite start due to the error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. The imports for Component C are as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { COLORS } from '../../styles/COLORS';
import BackButton from '../widgets/BackButton';
import backImage from '../../../assets/navigation/leftArrow.png';
import { SECTIONS } from './consts';
import setStatusBarColor from '../utils/StatusBarColorFunctions';
```

The error pointed at line 2, where Constants is imported. I commented out the line and ran the test again, and then pointed out the import statement for View, Text, etc., particularly at TouchableOpacity. I read some other posts that adding "type":"module" to the package.json file could resolve the issue, but I did not have issues with the two other components undergoing similar tests. If I change the file to require statements instead of import statements, it resolves the issue, but import statements are used for the other files and my tests run successfully. Is there a reason why this file in particular would have issues compared to the others, when they are are in the same directories?

Also I am fairly new to this site so if other information is needed from me please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Update: I am experiencing this with other files as well. If anyone has suggestions, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

all you need is a propterty at yow `package.json`

```
{
"name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
....
  "type": "module",
....
}
```

add the type module property into your package or if you are using babel make sure the first line of code read is

`request("@babel/register");`